# FIle upload won't work properly inside lightbox

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, lightbox

I'm using Lightbox Evolution:

http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-lightbox-evolution/115655

to open a lightbox when an image is clicked. The lightbox contains a `<input type="file" />` tag. The tag works perfectly on its own, but when inside the lightbox, the .php file doesn't receive the `$_FILES` parameter.

**index.html**

```js
<script>
$('#uploadFiles').live('change', function(event){
    $("#preview").html('');
    $("#preview").html('<img src="images/spinner.gif" title="Uploading..."/>');
    $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
        target: '#preview'
    }).submit();
});
</script>
```

```html
<div id='left-picture'>
    <a href="lightbox[width]=524&lightbox[height]=178#form-id" class="lightbox">
        <div id="preview">
            <img src="images/default_profile_image.jpg" width="192" height="225" />;
        </div>
    </a>
    <div id="form-id" style="display:none;">
        <form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="up.php">
            <input type="file" name="uploadFiles[]" id="uploadFiles" />
        </form>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

**upload.php**

```php
<?php
if(isset($_FILES["uploadFiles"]))
{
    echo '<img src="'.$theImage.'" class="preview">';
}
?>
```

Comment: ajaxForm isn't a part of jQuery. Are you including the proper plugins to make this work?

Comment: 1. You should ask the author at codecanyon. 2. Where is `$theImage` defined?

Comment: Have you tried using JQuery('#uploadFiles') ...    instead of $('#uploadfiles') ...  for your variables?   It sounds like there might be a conflict.  Are you sure you are loading only one JQuery file as well?  Have you tried "no conflict"?

Comment: @TravMcKinney Yes all files are being included. LightBox pops up, and I can select a file. But when it comes time to submit the file, `upload.php` receives nothing from the `<input/ >`.

Comment: Are you saying the post arrives (in up.php) , but $_FILES is empty? In which case do ANY file uploads work as it ssounds like a PHP settings issue; the lightbox may be a red herring.

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm using this too: 

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/ 

Could there be a conflict between it and lightbox?